# How can I improve the performance of select query on View?

Tags: oracle

I have created a view consisting of the union of 8 tables resulting in around 4 million records. There are indexes on all the tables involved. Still, a select query takes very long time to execute. Is there any way I can improve the performance?

View definition:

```
Create view view1(a,b,c,d) AS
select a,b,c,d from
table1
UNION ALL
select a,b,c,d from
table2
UNION ALL
select a,b,c,d from
table3
UNION ALL
select a,b,c,d from
table4
UNION ALL
select a,b,c,d from
table5....
--so on till table8;
```

Select query:

```
select a,b,c,d 
  from view1 
 where a=1 and b=-1 
 order by c;
```

Index detail:

Index on `a`,`b` and `c` on all tables.

Comment: First advice: make sure you are using `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, and understand the difference. Besides that, without at least posting some sample code and some idea of a query plan no one can help at all. Are you selecting from the view with any criteria or just selecting the lot?

Comment: Hello user2994919, please show us some code so that we can further assist you.

Comment: This sounds like a horrible data model. Why do you have 8 tables with the same structure? A single table with 4 million rows would be a *much* better choice.

Comment: Try some hints is all i can say with this minimal level of detail.

Comment: These tables have different meanings and they don't have whole table structure same. It is just few attributes are same which are combined in view.

Comment: Make sure your statistics are up to date. And show us explain plan output.

Comment: Please execute "explain plan for select a,b,c,d from view1 where a=1 and b=-1 order by c" and then post the output here of "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right Indexes in place, may be that you have stale statistics; if so, update with DBMS_STATS package function:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(your_schema, 'table1', estimate_percent=>100, cascade=>true, method_opt=>'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO');
```

With this command Oracle automatically collect histograms too, useful in the case of skewed distribution of you data.

May be that the Optimizer prefers a Full table Scan anyway.
What's the selectivity of the columns a and b? If you have too many rows to be selected (or, even better, too many blocks to be scanned), you Indexes are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues related to performance of views is discussed in link below

http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_hints_views.htm

Getting the explain plan will shed light on what is actually happening.

You should also compare the execution time of query without the view   to check if there are additional overheads of using the view

query would be like

select a,b,c,d from ((select a,b,c,d from table1 where  a=1 and b=-1) UNION ALL (select a,b,c,d from table2 where  a=1 and b=-1) ...) order by c;

Please check if the indexes are being used from the explain plan in both cases.

There are many reasons like type conversions or missing statistics due to which index may not being used

Comment: I disagree with practically everything in that article. There are too many statements in there that are only-true-sometimes. For example, "a view is usually only used in ad-hoc query systems wher [sic] a beginner is writing SQL and you want to hide the complexity of the SQL".

Comment: I found a few suggestions useful like "Re-write the SQL without the view", "Developers will often query a subset of the complex view, not realizing that all tables in the view will be joined" which may be happening in this case etc. I think the best approach is to study the explain plan and than take actions

Comment: There are a few useful nuggets, but I have no idea how to account for something like: "To periodically refresh a materialized view, you can use a mechanism that's similar to an Oracle snapshot." A materialized view *is* a snapshot! They just renamed snapshots to "materialized views" simply ages ago! Or: "Remember, any time the optimizer gets 'confused,' it will perform an unnecessary full-table scan." ... or it will not. There's no code path in the optimiser for "if confused then ..."